# How to re-size and drag an image selected from a folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, select

I want to re-size and drag an image which is selected by user from a folder. i could do it seperately. But when i combined select image from a folder and then resize and drag it, i didn't work. 
the selected image is displayed, but it is immovable. i don't know how to do it. Can anyone tell me?

This is the final code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link class="jsbin" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }

</style>


<body>

   <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />

</body>


<style type="text/css">
#blah {
width: 260px;
height:300px;
padding: 0;
}
#blah img {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}



</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#blah").resizable();
    $("#blah").draggable();

});
</script>

<script>
function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah')
                    .attr('src', e.target.result)
                    .width(150)
                    .height(200);
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

</script>
</head>

</html>
```

Below is the screenshot of result. Even image is displayed, no option to resize( the edge is not resizble bottom right edge)
[image]

Comment: Seems to work on latest version of Chrome and FF with jQueryUI 1.9.2
See http://jsfiddle.net/LyMes/1/

Comment: Check your error console there might be errors

Comment: @AmGates its not working. I can select image and it is displayed. But can't drag or resize.
Which library to be replaced; first script or second one? Replacing also didn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like problem with the jquery.ui library you are linking. USe the below displayed tag

```
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Hope this solves your problem.